How to plot confidence band for Weibull linear fitting?
I have a reliability dataset and want to plot using linear fitting by assuming Weibull distribution.
data={4.4472, 4.60019, 5.73709, 7.00806, 7.86835, 11.2546, 13.823, \
14.8316, 15.5077, 15.8661, 16.235, 17.4091, 18.1981, 18.6303, \
18.6407, 22.9107, 23.4553, 23.4773, 26.9209, 27.5708, 29.5517, \
30.9302, 33.8849, 35.4922, 36.3334, 37.1624, 37.188, 37.1944, \
38.0554, 38.9258, 39.8223, 40.7615, 43.6816, 46.8222, 47.8639, \
50.1224, 50.1391, 51.3221, 51.324, 63.0961, 63.1088, 66.1042, \
67.6106, 77.627, 83.2349, 91.2689, 107.175, 109.676, 117.506, \
128.843, 134.913}

Below is the plot in Excel to show how the data are fit.
But what I need is the confidence bands as shown in JMP.
(The Confidence Interval method I used in JMP is Wald.)
How can I plot such linear fitting curve with confidence bands in Mathematica, assuming Weibull distribution?
Related python based introduction

Need a minimal working example of what you have tried and which bit is not working.

I had thought it was just a functionality I did not know about until I found out it is indeed complicated in mathematics. In JMP there are two methods of calculating Confidence Interval, Wald and  Likelihood. I guess the first one(default) may refer to the Fisher Matrix Confidence Bounds and now I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the variance-covariance matrix based on Fisher Information Matrix after MLE parameter estimation. @Edmund

The calculations for the covariance matrix are found in my answer.

@houzw found the ProbabilityScalePlot function which produces the plot you desire but without the confidence bands:
data = {4.4472, 4.60019, 5.73709, 7.00806, 7.86835, 11.2546, 13.823, 
    14.8316, 15.5077, 15.8661, 16.235, 17.4091, 18.1981, 18.6303, 
    18.6407, 22.9107, 23.4553, 23.4773, 26.9209, 27.5708, 29.5517, 
    30.9302, 33.8849, 35.4922, 36.3334, 37.1624, 37.188, 37.1944, 
    38.0554, 38.9258, 39.8223, 40.7615, 43.6816, 46.8222, 47.8639, 
    50.1224, 50.1391, 51.3221, 51.324, 63.0961, 63.1088, 66.1042, 
    67.6106, 77.627, 83.2349, 91.2689, 107.175, 109.676, 117.506, 
    128.843, 134.913} // Sort;

ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Weibull", PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ReferenceLineStyle -> {{Black, Dashing[{}]}}, GridLines -> Automatic]


In the literature there are several ways to display the data points, the "fitted line", and the confidence bands.  Some of those ways are more for convenience rather having substantial statistic justification but there is a long history of that.  As an example, the default process to find the fitted line is to join (and later extend) the two points representing the 25th and 75th percentiles of the data (as the "true" function is a line for the Weibull distribution).  That is the default for ProbabilityScalePlot.
I would suggest using maximum likelihood to find the Weibull parameter estimates.
mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]]
(* {\[Alpha] -> 1.39016, \[Beta] -> 47.4936} *)

A nonparametric approach
Because for any continuous distribution the distribution of the Weibull CDF evaluated at the $k$-th order statistic is a beta distribution with parameters $k$ and $n+1-k$, we can construct confidence intervals for every observed order statistic.
n = Length[data];
t = Table[{data[[k]], 
    InverseCDF[BetaDistribution[k, n + 1 - k], 0.025],
    InverseCDF[BetaDistribution[k, n + 1 - k], 0.975]}, {k, 1, n}];

Adding and connecting these points to a ProbabilityScalePlot requires appropriate scaling:
weibull = Log[-Log[1 - #1]] &;  (* Scaling function *)
Show[ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Weibull", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True,ReferenceLineStyle -> {{Black, Dashing[{}]}},
  GridLines -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"TDDB", "Percentage"}],
 
 ListPlot[{t[[All, {1, 2}]], t[[All, {1, 3}]]},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", {weibull, InverseFunction[weibull]}},
  Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> LightGray, Filling -> 1 -> {2}]]


Approximate confidence bands
Here is a method to approximate 95% confidence bands using the Delta Method:
cdf = FullSimplify[CDF[WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], x],
  Assumptions -> x > 0]
(* 1 - E^-(x/\[Beta])^\[Alpha] *)

(* Approximate standard error of the cdf at a point x using Delta Method *)
(* Log of the likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], data];
(* Approximate covariance matrix for the Weibull parameter  estimators *)
cov = -Inverse[D[logL, {{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, 2}]] /. mle
(* Standard error *)
se = Sqrt[(D[cdf, {{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, 1}] . cov . D[cdf, {{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, 1}]) /. mle];

(* Now generate approximate 95% confidence bands *)
points = Table[{x, Max[cdf - 1.96  se, 0.00001], 
     Min[cdf + 1.96  se, 0.99999]} /. mle, {x, 4, 140}];

Include these confidence bands...
Show[ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Weibull", PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ReferenceLineStyle -> {{Black, Dashing[{}]}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"TDDB", "Percentage"}],
 
 ListPlot[{points[[All, {1, 2}]], points[[All, {1, 3}]]}, PlotStyle -> LightGray,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", {weibull, InverseFunction[weibull]}},
  Joined -> True, Filling -> 1 -> {2}]]


Finally...adding in the maximum likelihood fit:
dist = WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]] /. mle
weibullLine = {{Min[data], CDF[dist, Min[data]]}, {Max[data], CDF[dist, Max[data]]}};
Show[ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Weibull", PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ReferenceLineStyle -> {{Black, Dashing[{}]}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"TDDB", "Percentage"}],
 
 ListPlot[{points[[All, {1, 2}]], points[[All, {1, 3}]]}, PlotStyle -> LightGray,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", {weibull, InverseFunction[weibull]}},
  Joined -> True, Filling -> 1 -> {2},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Black, Green, LightGray}, 
    {"Default fit", "Maximum likelihood fit", "Approximate 95% confidence bands"}]],
 
 ListPlot[weibullLine, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Green,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", {weibull, InverseFunction[weibull]}}]]



The example image does not use logarithmic coordinates, so obviously your line is different from what is required.

@houzw Would you give more details?  The OP's horizontal axis on both figures is shown on a log scale.  And, yes, I did not produce code to match the OP's vertical scales but rather I followed the standard use of quantiles for the vertical axis.  I'll wait to see if the OP doesn't like that.

@houzw  In a little while I'll temporarily hide this answer and then add in the vertical axis to match what JMP produces.

I tend to think that the original poster wants ProbabilityScalePlot.

@houzw  You are correct.  I've now completely changed my answer to attempt to answer the question actually asked.

@JimB Thank you for the answer. I see some differences between your plot and the JMP. The first point is outside the JMP confidence bands while in your post it is not. And from the JMP plot it looks like the MLE fitting line is vertically the center of the confidence bands but not the case in your plot. Is it because a different method applied? I've also noticed there are two types of confidence bands, Confidence Bounds on Time (Type 1, x-axis) and Confidence Bounds on Reliability (Type 2, y-axis). Maybe this is another difference in the two plots.

@metroidman In fact, I was confused when I was writing my answer: what is the meaning of this confidence band?

@houzw I'm not sure that this will clear up the confusion but both of the confidence bands I've presented are "pointwise confidence intervals at every sample point".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands.

@houzw There is engineering meaning. Sometimes you will be asked to provide the cumulative failure rate or lifetime based on 95% CL. This is often required in reliability qualification report. There are a lot of ways to calculate the CB. I'm wandering how those popular statistic commertial tools(Weibull++/JMP/Minitab) do and trying to figure out with MMA.

If you're asking to duplicate in Mathematica what JMP does, then you're going to need to tells us what JMP does.  Giving us a Python-based introduction doesn't say what JMP does.  If you don't know what JMP does, then how do you know what JMP provides is what you want?

@JimB Yes, but the difficulty is there is very limited information how JMP does. Not to be obsessed with that plot, I think the way you provided is a very good approach.

I lack the details of the method used for your figure, so the result is slightly different.
Clear["`*"]
data = {4.4472, 4.60019, 5.73709, 7.00806, 7.86835, 11.2546, 13.823, 
   14.8316, 15.5077, 15.8661, 16.235, 17.4091, 18.1981, 18.6303, 
   18.6407, 22.9107, 23.4553, 23.4773, 26.9209, 27.5708, 29.5517, 
   30.9302, 33.8849, 35.4922, 36.3334, 37.1624, 37.188, 37.1944, 
   38.0554, 38.9258, 39.8223, 40.7615, 43.6816, 46.8222, 47.8639, 
   50.1224, 50.1391, 51.3221, 51.324, 63.0961, 63.1088, 66.1042, 
   67.6106, 77.627, 83.2349, 91.2689, 107.175, 109.676, 117.506, 
   128.843, 134.913};
dataP = Table[{data[[i]], (i - 0.5)/Length[data]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[data]}];
dataF = {Log[#[[1]]], Log[-Log[1 - #[[2]]]]} & /@ dataP;
fit = LinearModelFit[
   Table[{Log[data[[i]]], Log[-Log[1 - (i - 0.5)/Length[data]]]}, {i, 
     1, Length[data]}], {1, x}, x];
Show[ListPlot[dataP, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{Log[#] &, Exp[#] &}, {Log[-Log[1 - #]] &, 
     1 - E^-E^# &}}, AspectRatio -> 1], 
 Plot[Evaluate@Flatten@{fit["BestFit"],
     fit["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.9973]}, {x, 1.42,
    5}, Filling -> {3 -> {2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97][#] & /@ {2, 3, 3})]]



Using regression for estimate parameters of a distribution is usually inappropriate.  Maximum likelihood estimates or method of moments estimation should be considered.

@JimB What you said is indeed more appropriate, but I don't know how to give the confidence band shown in the picture based on them.

Thank you for pointing out the corresponding function!

After looking at references for this It does appear that for many decades "least squares" has been used to construct parameter estimates and confidence bands out of convenience rather than a more statistically justified approach either using maximum likelihood or a nonparametric method.
